# Tesla API Authorization : Step 1

Tags: oauth, postman, response

I'm trying to complete step 1 of the Tesla API Authorization([docs](https://tesla-api.timdorr.com/api-basics/authentication)):

If I don't include the response_type, I get this error:
`{ "error": { "message": "Missing required parameter: response_type", "code": 400, "reason": "AuthorizationError", "referenceID": "929625d426a94badb8b05233ea5e3958-1686939229741" } }`

If I include the response type as "code", I get this error:
`{ "error": { "message": "Unsupported response type: \"code\"", "code": 501, "reason": "AuthorizationError", "referenceID": "b7aa433afa194531977d6362f3c0e037-1686939263408" } }`

Am I using OAuth incorrectly? The API spec says that the response_type HAS to be "code", yet this is showing that it's unsupported?

[Postman Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7JV6.png)

I've tried swapping out "code" for "token", "id_token", and a bunch of other combinations thereof.  Not entirely sure what's going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You must provide all the request parameters as provided in the table, i.e.:
`client_id`, `code_challenge`, `code_challenge_method`, `redirect_uri`, `response_type`, `scope`, `state`, `is_in_app`.

So, a sample working url could be:

https://auth.tesla.com/oauth2/v3/authorize?client_id=ownerapi&code_challenge=3a48088303be990fabca077c7640349f4fbf12ad511096qq514c93eece34d1fe&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.tesla.com%2Fvoid%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+offline_access+phone&state=bpn2Csf7M5FTK0m1&is_in_app=true

Note that after this step, you get the redirect url from which to get the authorization code, which I couldn't figure out how to successfully implement yet using Expo and React Native.

Comment: The code challenge you use here seems not to be the PKCE safe base64url-encoded SHA256 digest, is it normal ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is encoded. Definitely it is meant to be encoded, otherwise it shouldn't work